# ExtJs : Populate ComboBox from Json Response

Tags: json, ajax, extjs, combobox

I am using Extjs 5.1 to populate combobox with the data returned from AJAX call.

The AJAX call returns the product names, but the combobox populates the data in single row with comma separated(requirement is to populate the items in separate row with one item in each row).

### Combo Box logic

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    queryMode: 'remote',
    itemId: 'prodListCombo',
    name: 'prodNumber',
    emptyText: '-- Select Product --',
    width: '290px',
    height: '32px',
    autoSelect: false,
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    selectOnFocus: false,
    minChars: 1,
    padding: '0 0 0 5',

    listConfig: {
        maxHeight: 110,
        emptyText: 'No Products found.'
    },
    triggerAction: 'all',
    displayField: 'prodNumber',
    store: productStore,
    editable: false,
    typeAhead: false,
    forceSelection: true,
    dataIndex: 'prodNumber',
    lastQuery: '',
    listeners: {
        click: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {

        },
        beforequery: function(queryPlan, eOpts) {
            var prodInstore = "";
            var prodInstoreArrray = [];
            //MMACMF-74
            Prod_Num = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#prodListCombo')[0];

            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: MaintenanceAdvisor.util.AppUrls.appurls.getCustomerProds,
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    "customerName": 'CUST A'
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    debugger;
                    var response2 = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    var datafiles = response2.data; ** -- > datafiles has the data of PROD A and PROD B. **


                        if (datafiles.length === 0) {

                        } else {
                            store.removeAll();
                            store.add(datafiles);
                            Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#prodListCombo")[0].setValue(store.getData('prodNumber').items);

                            for (var iProd = 0; iProd < datafiles.length; iProd++) {
                                var ProdId = store.getAt(iProd).data.prodNumber;

                                prodInstore += ProdId;
                                prodInstore += ',';

                            }
                            prodInstore = prodInstore.substr(0, prodInstore.length - 1);
                            prodInstoreArrray = prodInstore.split(",");

                            //Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#prodListCombo")[0].setValue(prodInstoreArrray);

                        }
                },
                failure: function(response) {
                    alert("failed");
                }
            });

        } //beforequery
    } //listeners
},
```

### The JSON response

```
datafiles: Array(2)
0:
    id: "CustomerCenter-31"
    customerName: null
    customerType: "OPERATOR"
    **productNumber: "PROD A"**
    __proto__: Object
1:
    id: "CustomerCenter-32"
    customerName: null
    customerType: "OPERATOR"
    **productNumber: "PROD B"**
    __proto__: Object
length: 2
```

***Java code returns Map for the AJAX call request.***

But the data in the combobox is with comma-separated.

[image: Second combobox displaying values with comma separated]

Please guide me for any changes in the script to populate it in each row.

Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing but I see that you have used some unnecessary approaches like the `beforequery` event, the loop to mount the array, and so on. I'll suggest another approach, more in line with the features of the framework.

Since your combox is `editable: false`, use the `select` event instead of `beforequery` to call the second combobox fill. To fill it, instead of using `Ext.Ajax.request` directly, it may be more interesting to configure the [proxy.api](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html) of the store and use the [Ext.data.Store.html method load](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.data.Store.html#method-load) event after setting the parameter chosen in the first combobox. The store must have an associated `model` or the `fields` property filled in with the same properties as the returned JSON.

I used the [Jakeplaceholder Fake Online REST API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) to set up an example:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {

        var firstStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                api: {
                    read: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'
                }
            },
            fields: [
                { name: 'id' },
                {  name: 'title' }
            ]
        });

        var secondStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                api: {
                    read: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'
                }
            },
            fields: [
                { name: 'id'  },
                { name: 'title' }
            ]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'Test Ajax Combobox',
            layout: 'form',
            maximized: true,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    label: 'First Combo',
                    editable: false,
                    valueField: 'id',
                    displayField: 'title',
                    store: firstStore,
                    listeners: {
                        select: function(field, record, e){
                            field.next().reset();

                            alert('Selected a new item on first combobox store.');
                            field.up('window').mask('Wait...');
                            secondStore.load({
                                params: {
                                    albumId: record.get('id')
                                },
                                callback: function(){
                                    field.up('window').unmask();
                                    alert('Arrived the response of the request and automatically filled the second combobox store.');
                                }
                            });

                            // Or...
                            // secondStore.getProxy().setExtraParam('albumId',  record.get('id'));
                            // secondStore.reload({
                            //     callback: function(){
                            //         field.up('window').unmask();
                            //         alert('Arrived the response of the request and automatically filled the second combobox store.');
                            //     }
                            // });
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    editable: false,
                    label: 'Second Combo',
                    store: secondStore,
                    valueField: 'id',
                    displayField: 'title'
                }
            ]
        }).show();

    }
});
```

Check out the doc on the links.

Any questions, leave a comment. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: I like this approach, but I can't use this way in my project. Thank You :)